# exchange view animation

Tags: android, animation, view

Does anyone have experience on view animation? I have met a problem, In my application, I have an activity, have two views, left and right, and I want to exchange these two views dynamically(left to right and right to left), when the view from left to right need view animation, I mean I need redraw the view in the process of moving, not just start an animation. Actually, Those means that we can move one view from one position to another position, and have animation effect. Not start an
animation, then removeView andView.....

Answer (score 0):

You want [Property Animation](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html) - sadly it's still just for Honeycomb and above.